# Can't anchor LinearLayout to bottom of parent using CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android

I'm trying to get my LinearLayout to appear at the bottom of the parent (which is the bottom of the screen) but I'm not able to. It always appears at the top of the parent.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    tools:context=".app.ui.tutorial.TutorialActivity">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#00FFFFFF">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
            android:text="Toolbar Title"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:tint="@color/green500"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_pager_section_position" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: you are mistaking constraintlayout with coordinatorlayout.

Comment: You are using constrains that belong to a ConstrainsLayout but using a CoordinatorLayout instead.. Your root layout should be changed to ConstrainsLayout

Comment: You're right. This is what happens when you rely upon Android Studio adding stuff through it's designer instead of hardcoding it manually, which is what I did in the past. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Can't anchor LinearLayout to bottom of parent using CoordinatorLayout

Beacause you have added the constraint of **`ConstraintLayout`** in your `LinearLayout` while your root layout is **`CoordinatorLayout`**

You need to set **`android:layout_gravity="bottom"`** in your **`LinearLayout`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    tools:context=".app.ui.tutorial.TutorialActivity">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
         />

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#00FFFFFF">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
            android:text="Toolbar Title"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_pager_section_position"
            android:tint="@color/green500" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]